# Regex : Remove Repeated and Single X from text

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that will remove the repeated X symbol from a text, but if only X is repeated more than once and has no other character nearby. But it needs to remove a single X character from a text too.

For example, if the given text is

**"Hi, myX name is XXXX Farid, X glad to meet youXXX"**,

then the result must be

**"Hi, myX name is Farid, glad to meet youXXX"**

Comment: `\\b` is a boundary. `"Hi, myX name is XXXX Farid, X glad to meet youXXX".replaceAll("\\b[X]+\\b", "")` will get rid of the lone X(s). But it won't remove all the extra whitespace you're left with.

Comment: "*repeated more than once* - so  here `"some XX is OK*" XX should not be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\\bX+(?= |$)|(?<= )X+\\b`, this regex matches sequences of the letter 'X' that fulfill one of two conditions:

1. The 'X' sequence is surrounded by word boundaries (`\\b`) and is followed by either a space or the end of the string (`(?= |$)`).
2. The 'X' sequence is preceded by a space and is followed by a word boundary (`(?<= )X+\\b`).

Example:

```java
String text = "Hi, myX name is XXXX Farid, X glad to meet youXXX";
String result = text.replaceAll("\\bX+(?= |$)|(?<= )X+\\b", "");
System.out.println(result); //Hi, myX name is  Farid,  glad to meet youXXX
```

Comment: Backtracking. Shudder. JWZ had a point about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove such a word nicely in one go:

```
              # Match either
\h*X+$        # 0+ horizontal whitespaces followed by 1+ 'X' at the end of string
|             # or
\bX+\h+       # a standalone series of 'X' followed by 1+ horizontal whitespaces.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZanIZh/1).

The first branch matches `X+` at the end of string and any horizontal whitespaces *preceding* that, whereas the second matches any other instances and any horizontal whitespaces *following* that. This is how the matches look like:

```
XXX Hi, myX name is XXXX Farid, X glad to meet youXXX XX
^^^^                ^^^^^       ^^                   ^^^
 2                    2         2                     1
```

To provide another solution, splitting and filtering also works:

<sub>(The following function is mainly written by ChatGPT, but I have validated that it works.)</sub>

```java
static String filterX(String input) {
  String[] words = input.split(" ");
    
  String[] filteredWords = Arrays.stream(words)
          .filter(word -> !word.matches("^X+$"))
          .toArray(String[]::new);
    
  return String.join(" ", filteredWords);
}
```

Try it [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ui8pXT).

For educational purposes, the following is a more complex version of that regex. It does essentially the same thing, but doesn't require duplicating `X+`.

```
(?:           # Match either
  \h          # a horizontal whitespace
  (?=\S+$)    # iff the following word ends at the end of string
|             # or
  \b          # a normal word boundary
)             # succeeded by
X+            # 1 or more 'X'
\h*           # and 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZanIZh/2).